# how to merge this list of dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x

```
input = [{
    'roll_no': ['123445', '1212'],
    'school_id': 1
}, {
    'roll_no': ['HA-4848231'],
    'school_id': 2
}, {
    'roll_no': ['473427'],
    'school_id': 2
}, {
    'roll_no': ['092112'],
    'school_id': 5
}]
```

how to merge this list of dictionary using same key `school_id`. Suppose if `school_id` is 2 then merge them in one dictionary. Below output you can see 2 and 3rd dictionary is merged because both have same `school_id` is 2.

Answer:

```
[{
    'roll_no': ['123445', '1212'],
    'school_id': 1
}, {
    'roll_no': ['473427', 'HA-4848231'],
    'school_id': 2
}, {
    'roll_no': ['092112'],
    'school_id': 5
}]
```

Comment: could you please explain what do you need

Comment: i edited question that what i need

Comment: Can you also describe what you're doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [4]: from collections import defaultdict

In [16]: a
Out[16]:
[{'roll_no': ['123445', '1212'], 'school_id': 1},
 {'roll_no': ['HA-4848231'], 'school_id': 2},
 {'roll_no': ['473427'], 'school_id': 2},
 {'roll_no': ['092112'], 'school_id': 5}]

In [5]: ans = defaultdict(list)
In [10]: for i in a:
    ...:     ans[i["school_id"]].extend(i["roll_no"])
In [11]: ans
Out[11]:
defaultdict(list,
            {1: ['123445', '1212'],
             2: ['HA-4848231', '473427'],
             5: ['092112']})

In [15]: [{"schoold_id":k,"roll_no":v} for k,v in ans.items()]
Out[15]:
[{'schoold_id': 1, 'roll_no': ['123445', '1212']},
 {'schoold_id': 2, 'roll_no': ['HA-4848231', '473427']},
 {'schoold_id': 5, 'roll_no': ['092112']}]
```

Comment: ans = defaultdict(list)
for i in Input1:
    ans[i["school_id"]].extend(i["roll_no"])
    [{"school_id": k, "roll_no": v} for k, v in ans.items()]
    print(ans) i have written this and i got only this ans: {1: ['123445', '1212'], 2: ['HA-4848231', '473427'], 5: ['092112']})

Comment: Any problem you are facing?